# Unable to read property file on the application web server

Tags: jakarta-ee, classpath, war

I was able to run the code in my local liberty websphere application server but when I generated a War then deploy it into websphere server I was not able to get the property file working.

I believe the error is in the build.xml where the path generated is wrong so the property file is not read. I am using ant build

Below is my build.xml (the property file name is DBInfo.properties)

```
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<project name="WS" basedir="." default="build" >
  <property name="src.dir" value ="src" />
  <property name="web.dir" value ="build"/>
  <property name="build.dir" value="${web.dir}/classes" />
  <property name="webcontent" location = "WebContent" />

  <path id="lib">
    <fileset dir="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/lib ">
      <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
    <pathelement path="${build.dir}"/>
  </path>

  <target name="init" >
    <copy toDir="${web.dir}" >
      <fileset file="${webcontent}/WEB-INF">
        <include name="**" />
      </fileset>
    </copy>
  </target>

  <target name="build">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir} />
    <javac includeantruntime="false" destdir="${build.dir}" source="1.8" target="1.8">
      <src path="${src.dir}"/>
      <classpath refid ="lib"/>
    </javac>
    <copy file="${src.dir}/DBInfo.properties" tofile="${web.dir}/classes/DBinfo.properties" overwrite="true" />
  </target>

  <target name="war" depends="build" >
    <war destfile="WS.war" webxml="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml" >
      <fileset dir= "${web.dir}" >
        <include name = "**/*.*"/>
        <exclude name ="**/${build.dir}/**" />
      </fileset>

      <class dir="${build.dir}" />
    </war>
  </target>
```

Below is the class which it uses the property file. It works on local server but when deploy the war it wasnt able to find it.

```
public class ConnectionManager {
...definable attribute
public static Connection getConnection() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    Connection con = null;

    try {
        InputStream path = ConnectionManager.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("DBInfo.properties");
        props.load(path);
...
```

And the file hierarchy looks like this
After build

```
WS
|-java resources
|      |-src
|      |-DBInfo.properties
|-Libraries
|-build
|   |-classes
|   |    |-com ..
|   |    |-DBInfo.properties
|   |-css
|   |-META-INF
|   |-WEB-INF
|-WebContent
```

Does anyone know why am I not able to get the property file after I generated war and deployed on the server? (Websphere)

Comment: Is there an exception? Are you sure the properties file is in the WAR?

Comment: yes, when I went to server app in unix I was able to see the properties file next to the classes folder. The exception is the null pointer for the file not found.

Comment: The build file in your question is not valid XML, due to the first line inside the `<war>` task ending with `?`.  Because of that, I wouldn’t expect Ant to even start executing any tasks.  Are you showing us the actual build file that’s causing your problem?

Comment: that was a typo. A war package is generated